# JVM (lucee) Metaspace increases constantly

Tags: java, memory-leak

I have a lucee (ColdFusion) server in production.

At first, we encountered OS memory exhaustion. We reduced the `-Xmx2048m` to half available memory and set `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1000m`.

After a while though, the tomcat of lucee reported OutOfMemory errors and required a restart.

Since the metaspace is in addition to the heap and by default is not limited, this indicates that the metaspace is filling up.

I have then added a regular `jcmd <pid> VM.metaspace` to verify this assumption.
In the morning, I have:

```
 garbage-first heap   total 1572864K, used 959885K [0x0000000080000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  region size 1024K, 249 young (254976K), 18 survivors (18432K)
 Metaspace       used 99985K, capacity 102839K, committed 104996K, reserved 1114112K
  class space    used 7301K, capacity 8154K, committed 8320K, reserved 1015808K
```

and in the evening:

```
 garbage-first heap   total 1616896K, used 556546K [0x0000000080000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  region size 1024K, 25 young (25600K), 5 survivors (5120K)
 Metaspace       used 108125K, capacity 111035K, committed 113828K, reserved 1122304K
  class space    used 7509K, capacity 8463K, committed 8704K, reserved 1015808K
```

So metaspace is growing by about 8Mb per day !

I had found that JAXB had an issue that cause this behavior, so I tried that walkaround by adding `-Dcom.sun.xml.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.noOptimize=true` but it didn't help or maybe made it worse.

How can I find out what the heck is filling up my metaspace ?

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to find a solution to this, but there is an open ticket for it.I am currently having to restart my server periodically to prevent a crash.

Please see

https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-2904

and

https://dev.lucee.org/t/lucee-5-3-5-92-java-non-heap-memory-steadily-increases/6948/23

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/501900)